# Как изменить файл js на сайте с помощью Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Мне нужно изменять js файл сайта при загрузке на свой. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Что не понятно в вопросе?